# I'm trying to update a table with information based on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a list of SSNs (not real ones) connected to houseIDs.

I need to update a specific SSN's houseid based on a given address.

I have another table with houseIDs connected to HouseAddresses.

Here is what I have so far:

```
update persons
    set houseid = houses.houseid
from houses
where houses.houseaddress = 'Alma Street' 
    and persons.SSN = 675849512;
```

While this works, it doesn't update anything, and I know it should update one row.

I'm afraid I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense, because the join column itself is being updated, instead of being used to join.  Please show sample data and your expected output.

Comment: I actually fixed this, there was a somewhat unrelated problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
update persons
set persons.houseid = houses.houseid
from houses
where houses.houseaddress = 'Alma Street' and
persons.SSN = 675849512;
```

OR

```
update persons
set houseid = i.houseid
from (
  select houseid,houseaddress 
  from houses) i
where  i.houseaddress = 'Alma Street' and
persons.SSN = 675849512;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update your houseid from other table connected by address you should join tables by addresses

Look this

```
update persons
set houseid = (Select Top(1) houses.houseid from  
                 from houses
                 where houses.houseaddress = persons.address 
                 .....
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY IN THIS WAY:** Use `JOIN` for effective solution in the following way but in the below code I am taking `SSN` as the common column but you can replace it with one if different:

```
UPDATE p SET houseid = h.houseid
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN houses h ON h.SSN = p.SSN 
 AND h.houseaddress = 'Alma Street' 
 AND ----------
 --------
```

You can add more conditions according to you requirement in `AND` or add `WHERE` clause if required.